# Merging two JSON arrays using jq

Tags: json, jq

I'd like to join the arrays '.fileStats' and '.files' so that there's only one array.

**Initial JSON:**

```
{"arguments":{"torrents":[{"fileStats":[{"bytesCompleted":0,"priority":0,"wanted":false},{"bytesCompleted":0,"priority":0,"wanted":true},{"bytesCompleted":0,"priority":0,"wanted":true}],"files":[{"bytesCompleted":0,"length":30,"name":"1.txt"},{"bytesCompleted":0,"length":99,"name":"2.exe"},{"bytesCompleted":0,"length":4833317512,"name":"3.iso"}]}]},"result":"success"}
```

**Example of an object after the arrays are merged:**

```
{
  "bytesCompleted": 0,
  "length": 30,
  "name": "1.txt",
  "priority": 0,
  "wanted": true
}
```

I went about a different approach via 'flattening':

```
.arguments.torrents[] | map(to_entries) | flatten | group_by(.key)
```

but being able to select the objects based on '.wanted' being true/false and then retrieving '.name' is more desirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jq '.arguments.torrents[] | range(.fileStats|length) as $i| select(.fileStats[$i].wanted)| .fileStats[$i]+.files[$i]'
```

I think the above code does what you want. It gives the following output with your input.

```
{
  "bytesCompleted": 0,
  "priority": 0,
  "wanted": true,
  "length": 99,
  "name": "2.exe"
}
{
  "bytesCompleted": 0,
  "priority": 0,
  "wanted": true,
  "length": 4833317512,
  "name": "3.iso"
}
```

For more details please look up "Variable", "range", "length", "select", and "merge" in jq manual. https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/